# Powershell script for filtering parent and child folders, with further filter on files. Finally, copy

Tags: powershell-4.0

Is there a way to filter out a folder and then further filter out a folder from it's child and then filtering out certain files?

Parent:

> C:\XYZ\ABC\123
>
> C:\XYZ\ABC\789
>
> C:\XYZ\ABC\654

Filter out 123 and then

Child

> C:\XYZ\ABC\123\lmn
>
> C:\XYZ\ABC\123\pqr
>
> C:\XYZ\ABC\123\tru

Filter out **C:\XYZ\ABC\123\lmn**. Then copy all folders inside by only selecting **csv** files from them

All of this by maintaining the folder structure from

> 123\lmn\test1 (Only csv files)
>
> 123\lmn\test2 (Only CSV files)

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\XYZ\ABC\* | Foreach-Object {
$folderName = $_.BaseName
    if($folderName == "123"){
        Get-ChildItem C:\XYZ\ABC\$folderName\* | Foreach-Object {
        $childFolderName = $_.BaseName
        if($childFolderName == "lmn"){
             Get-ChildItem C:\XYZ\ABC\$folderName\$ childFolderName \*.csv |Foreach-Object {
                 $ExcelFile = import-csv $_
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

This should copy all csv file in the folder C:\XYZ\ABC\123\lmn. You just have to export them after your operation on them with the export fonction. Is this what you wanted?